# How come Doctrine2 doesn't have a preLoad event?

Tags: events, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm just curious why such event doesn't exist. Is there an obvious reason for it that I'm not seeing or there exists some sort of workaround?

Comment: I've no answer but I'm curious too :) What kind of stuff would you do before loading ?

Comment: I was trying to do something fancy with modifying the SQL right before the select statement, but I figured out that it can be done with SQL filters :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's obvious from my point of view.

> postLoad - The postLoad event occurs for an entity after the entity has been loaded into the current EntityManager from the database or after the refresh operation has been applied to it.

[Source](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events)

Since during so-called `preLoad` state you don't have any entities - why would you like to modify nothing with something?

Comment: Here's a [reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485360/doctrine-preload-listener-to-manipulate-querybuilder-before-execution) why it would be useful. Essentially adding a join to an entity to avoid lazy-loading, if it's ever called without the proper joins.

Comment: You know, postLoad called after actualData was collected.
But in case if  I use custom Type (for example FileType) and I want to set path and other staff in postLoad event, and for comparison in change sets i want to use not data from my custom type, but data which was set by postLoad event. And it's not possible

Comment: Making an entity locale aware before the data is being loaded would be one scenario where preload would be a cool feature