# Doctrine preLoad Listener to Manipulate QueryBuilder before Execution

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is there a way to manipulate a Doctrine 2.6 QueryBuilder (DQL) before the query is sent to the database?

So for example, if we always want two entities to be associated (without lazy loading) then we need to JOIN the other entity's table (for efficiency). So it would be great if we could check if the other entity was joined yet, and if not, join it automatically.

But doctrine doesn't have a [preLoad listener](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal another way. You can set eager mode for fetching entities in annotations:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(..., fetch="EAGER")
 */
```

For what else do you need `preLoad` listener?

If you want just modify every generated SQL before it will be executed you can use [SQL Filters](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html).

Comment: That's helpful, I'll have to try to remember my use case from 5 months ago to know if this would be a solution. We probably found some other work around. Thanks!